# Junk Mail Permutations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, factorial

An apartment block has $8$ tenants, each with a separate mail slot.
Twelve different pieces of junk mail are delivered.

$(a)$ In how many ways can the mail be delivered if two tenants
get three pieces of junk mail and six get one piece?

$(b)$ In how many ways can the mail be delivered if the only
restriction is that every tenant gets at least one piece of mail?

I am super confused on where to start with this question. For a, I tried $(8!/3!3!)$ which gave me $1120$ combinations, but that did not seem right. I also tried doing ($^8C_3)*(6!)$ which gave me $40320$ combinations.

I'd appreciate any help!

EDIT

I think I managed A, thank you guys. I'm now just stuck on part B of the questions. I feel like I'm just missing something super simple

Comment: Can you clarify whether the two tenants are fixed or can be any of the 8?

Comment: @DatBoi I believe the two tenants can be any of the eight, as long as any of the six other tenants only get one piece of mail

Comment: Are the pieces of junk mail really **different** , ie getting junk mail #1 and, say, junk mail #2 is different ? Asking because the wording reads "Twelve **different** pieces of junk mail..."

Comment: For part b, consider the number of tenants that get only 1 junk, and treat each case separately.

Comment: @Hannah where did you find this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) Number of ways to distribute different junk mails $ = \displaystyle {12 \choose 3} \cdot {9 \choose 3} \cdot 6!$

Explanation: choose $3$ junk mails for one of the two tenants who receive three junk mails each. Then choose $3$ from remaining $9$ for the other. Rest $6$ mails can be distributed to each of them in $6!$ ways.

If these $2$ tenants can be any two of them out of eight, then multiply the result by $ \ \displaystyle {8 \choose 2}$

b) Hint: Use Principle of Inclusion Exclusion or Stirling Number of the second kind. Using Stirling Number of the second kind ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind))

Comment: How do you use inc-exc here ?

Comment: @Bulbasaur you can see this as an example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3819688/in-how-many-ways-can-50-sweets-be-distributed-to-30-children-so-that-each-ch/3821326#3821326. Also, case by case is not effective because there are $5$ cases to consider - if each of them have at least one mail, you have i) one tenant receive $5$ mails ii) two tenants receive $3$ mails each iii) one tenant receives $4$ mails and one $2$ iv) one tenant receives $3$, two tenants receive $2$ each v) $4$ tenants receive two mails each and rest $4$ one.

Comment: thanks buddy ..